# Continuity of addition under the lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

Letting $\Bbb R_\ell$ denote $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology, prove that the function $f : \Bbb R_\ell \times \Bbb R_\ell \to \Bbb R_\ell$ defined by $f((x,y)) = x+y$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Computational error corrected.**

Start with a basic open set in the range, say $[a,b)$. Its inverse image under addition is

$$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:a\le x+y<b\}\;;$$

geometrically this is the diagonal strip between the lines $x+y=a$ and $x+y=b$, including the former edge but not the latter. Take a point $p=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ on the line $x+y=a$. The distance from $p$ to the line $x+y=b$ is $b-a$, but that’s in the direction perpendicular to the strip, i.e., in the direction parallel to the line $y=x$. Thus, the point on the line $x+y=b$ closest to $p$ is the point

$$q=\left\langle x_0+\frac1{\sqrt2}(b-a),y_0+\frac1{\sqrt 2}(b-a)\right\rangle\;,$$

and $p$ and $q$ are diagonally opposite corners of the open box

$$\left[x_0,x_0+\frac1{\sqrt2}(b-a)\right)\times\left[y_0,y_0+\frac1{\sqrt2}(b-a)\right)$$

in the Sorgenfrey topology. Now just check that the strip is the union of all such open boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The preimage of an open set $[a,b)$ is 
$$
\{(x,y)\colon a \le x+y < b\}.
$$
To prove that such a stripe is open in the product space, write it as the union of squares $[x,x+(b-a)/2) \times [a-x,a-x+(b-a)/2)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Is it okay that strip can be written as union of squares mentioned by you. If I take a=1, b=2, x=3. Then 3.5 is in [3,4) and -1.4 in [-2,-1) but 3.5 - 1.4 = 2.1 >2

Comment: i've corrected it...

Comment: I couldn't find a fault here. So why is there a '-1' ?